# How to change Kinematic to Dynamic through scrip? Rigidbody2d

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-4.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qZea.png)

Object have Dynamic. I need to change to Kinematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
rb.bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Kinematic;
```

[Reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-bodyType.html).